# Only safe or non null assserted calls are allowed on a nullable receiver type of arraylist

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

Just started using kotlin for android development.My arraylist is declared like this-

```
var day1: ArrayList<DietPlanDetailModel>? = null
```

Now I am trying to access an element by its position

```
    val dietPlan= day1[position]
```

but i am getting below compile time error-

> Only safe or non null assserted calls are allowed  on a nullable
>   receiver type of arraylist

Why am i getting this error and how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem is, that you defined the `ArrayList` as `nullable`. You have two options here:

1. don't define the variable `nullable` (this depends on your code):

```
var day1: ArrayList<DietPlanDetailModel> = ArrayList()
```

2. access your data-structure with a null check:

```
val dietPlan= day1?.get(position)
```

Comment: 'day1?.get(position)' will return null if day1 is null.Now what will happen if i try to acess fields of dietPlan which is null ?will it throw nullpointer exception?

Comment: When you work with the `nullable` types, you always have to consider the `null`-case too. This depends on your code what to do, when `dietPlan` is `null`. So think about what should happen, when no diet plan is returned.

Answer (score 7):

As defined, `day1` can be `null` but you're invoking a function by doing `[]`, which is basically the same as calling `day1.get(index)`.

This can throw a `NullpointerException`, which the Kotlin compiler tries to prevend. Thus, only safe calls like this are allowed: `day1?.get()`.

Answer (score 2):

You told compiler that your variable can be null (and assigned null to it).

`day1[position]` is essentially `day1.get(position)` which will crash with NPE if `day1` is `null` -> `null.get(position)`

If you can guarantee that `day1` will be initialized id recommend `lateinit` or just straight up assigning new Arraylist with declaration. Of course, simple `day1?.get(position)` works fine.