# Converting to kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm following [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#7) but now I want to convert the WordRepository class to kotlin. I'm extremely new to kotlin, so I tried to use [this online kotlin converter](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Java%20to%20Kotlin%20conversion/Task.kt) and copy pasted the java WordRepository class from the first link. Below is the original java code btw:

```
public class WordRepository {

   private WordDao mWordDao;
   private LiveData<List<Word>> mAllWords;

   WordRepository(Application application) {
       WordRoomDatabase db = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
       mWordDao = db.wordDao();
       mAllWords = mWordDao.getAllWords();
   }

   LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords() {
       return mAllWords;
   }


   public void insert (Word word) {
       new insertAsyncTask(mWordDao).execute(word);
   }

   private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Word, Void, Void> {

       private WordDao mAsyncTaskDao;

       insertAsyncTask(WordDao dao) {
           mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(final Word... params) {
           mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
           return null;
       }
   }
}
```

And below is the kotlin code that I get from the online converter:

```
class WordRepository internal constructor(application:Application) {
  private val mWordDao:WordDao
  internal val allWords:LiveData<List<Word>>
  init{
    val db = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application)
    mWordDao = db.wordDao()
    allWords = mWordDao.getAllWords()
  }
  fun insert(word:Word) {
    insertAsyncTask(mWordDao).execute(word)
  }
  private class insertAsyncTask internal constructor(dao:WordDao):AsyncTask<Word, Void, Void>() {
    private val mAsyncTaskDao:WordDao
    init{
      mAsyncTaskDao = dao
    }
    protected fun doInBackground(vararg params:Word):Void {
      mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0])
      return null
    }
  }
}
```

Take note that to make the code above work, I changed

```
WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application)
```

to

```
WordRoomDatabase.getInstance(application)
```

because I've also changed WordRoomDatabase to kotlin and it doesn't have the function getDatabase anymore. Here's how WordRoomDatabase looked like

```
abstract class WordRoomDatabase: RoomDatabase(){

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: WordRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): WordRoomDatabase? {
            if (INSTANCE == null){
                synchronized(WordRoomDatabase::class){
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            WordRoomDatabase::class.java, "sps.db")
                            .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }

        fun destroyInstance(){
            INSTANCE == null
        }
    }
}
```

However, the code doesn't work, specifically this part:

```
mWordDao = db.wordDao();
```

It displays the error

> Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a
>   nullable receiver of type AppDatabase?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only safe or non null assserted calls are allowed on a nullable receiver type of arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014469/only-safe-or-non-null-assserted-calls-are-allowed-on-a-nullable-receiver-type-of)

Comment: @JoeC I tried to follow the solution in the link you gave but then it display the error 'Type mismatch. Required wordDao, found wordDao?

Comment: My suggestion is to avoid converting code in such way, that can be helpful while learning kotlin and you already know java but it isn't an solution, learn kotlin and then rewrite it.

Comment: What does `WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase()` return?  Does it return an `AppDatabase`? Or does it return an `AppDatabase?`?

Comment: And just to help you, problem is that Java doesn't offer null-safe types, while kotlin does, as you can see you have `WordRoomDatabase?` which means that `INSTANCE` can be null, kotlin doesn't allow calling method on such types without checking if value is null or not.

Comment: @JoeC, it returns `INSTANCE: WordRoomDatabase? = null` as displayed above. Btw it's now getInstance instead of getDatabase.

Comment: @FilipRistic Hmm I think you suggestion is the best. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are returning an *nullable* instance (question marked type) when calling `WordRoomDatabase.getInstance()` because of it signature.

You can change your `getInstance` to:

```
    fun getInstance(context: Context): WordRoomDatabase {
        if (INSTANCE == null){
            synchronized(WordRoomDatabase::class){
                INSTANCE = when you call [https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls)Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        WordRoomDatabase::class.java, "sps.db")
                        .build()
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE as WordRoomDatabase
    }
```

---

For further understanding about nullable types and safe calls, here some useful links:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls

https://www.callicoder.com/kotlin-nullable-types-null-safety/

Comment: Thanks. But I've been wondering, what's the advantage or disadvantage of having the ability of getInstance to return null, as in the original copy pasted code?

Comment: The main advantage is you have not to check if getInstance is null, that means that you will a lot less of boilerplate code related to. This thank you can guarantee that you are never getting a null instance because you are always initializing it before returned. As disadvantage I don't see any by the moment

Comment: I've updated the post with two links that should be useful for a better understanding.