# Android Studio error - Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type ComponentName?

Tags: android

I would really appreciate if someone could help me solve the below problem.

I am trying to build APK in android studio and am getting the error.

Error:

```
e: D:\WT\ZY\3.0\app\src\main\java\com\app\zy\cameraX\cameraxbasic\utils\Utils.kt: (117, 34): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type ComponentName?
```

The piece of code is :

```
    fun isAppIsInBackground(context: Context): Boolean {
        var isInBackground = true
        val am = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            val runningProcesses = am.runningAppProcesses
            for (processInfo in runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (activeProcess in processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess == context.packageName) {
                            isInBackground = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            val taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1)
            val componentInfo = taskInfo[0].topActivity
            if (componentInfo.packageName == context.packageName) {
                isInBackground = false
            }
        }
```

The line of error is

```
    if (componentInfo.packageName == context.packageName) {
```

Appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only safe or non null assserted calls are allowed on a nullable receiver type of arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014469/only-safe-or-non-null-assserted-calls-are-allowed-on-a-nullable-receiver-type-of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your If clause to

```
if (componentInfo != null && componentInfo.packageName == context.packageName)
```